# Is it possible to broadcast to multiple headsets at once over A2DP?

Tags: android, audio, streaming, bluetooth, broadcast

I'm hoping to have an Android broadcast to multiple Bluetooth headsets at once - the idea is to have a radio-like stream that users of an app can tap into. It is important that all users hear the music in sync (that is, the song ends at the same time for everyone).
I have not been able to determine if A2DP will allow streaming to multiple receivers, but I'd be open to other streaming solutions if you have them. Extra points if Android and iOS devices can play with each other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think streaming to multiple devices over A2DP is currently supported.

Comment: I appreciate the answer - I was hoping to be pointed to some part of the spec itself that shows this is impossible...
I would upvote you if I had any reputation points!

Comment: There is nothing in the spec that prevents or prohibits this behavior, We have seen/built some devices (non android) that can do this functionality. In standard Android Bluez based bluetooth support I haven't seen this feature yet, someday it ming get supported. (You can accept the answer if it helps you - there is a tick below the up/down vote)

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html in BluetoothA2dp class overview: "Android only supports one connected Bluetooth A2dp device at a time".

Answer (score 1):

I have two Creative WP-380 that have ShareMe function that permit to listen the same stream audio in the same time. I and my wife watch movie with our linux notebook using that couple of headsets.

One is the master, bluetooth connected with the notebook, and the second is the slave, paired with the first.

Works excellent with our android tablets!

Answer (score 0):

It was possible with Windows Mobile 6.5 on a HTC Touch Pro 2 (a bad smartphone because of it´s slow CPU). I used two A2PD Headphones simultaneously.